# css is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: "#divID".css is not a function
```

and I have no idea what to do can anyone help?

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){
   console.log(( "#divID" ).css("display") == "none");
   console.log(( "#divID" ).css("display"));
   if($( "#divID" ).css("display") == "none"){
      console.log("showing");
      $("#divID").css("display", "");
   } else {
      console.log("hiding");
      $("#divID").css("display", "none");
   }
   console.log(" ");
});
```

Comment: The code lacks a `$` here: `console.log(( "#divID" ).css("display") == "none");` and on the next line.

Comment: A per the close reasons: _'This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.'_

Comment: @HoboSapiens I don't disagree with the very-well-thought-through close text. However a question with the subject "css is not a function" might actually be a question that can help many future answer seekers. Having missed a dollar-sign is not always a typographical error. It could just as well be the cause of insufficient syntactical understanding.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen The text is SO design, directly from a CV reason. Typo is a typo, you just can't get around of it. OP has got an error message showing very clearly why it is thrown, and sitll they have to ask. The only sufficent place for these questions is a trash can, i.e. close and delete.

Comment: @Teemu, I disagree. *"this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers"* is not the case IMO. But sure, **the system** is democratic and per definition *always right* so go on and vote for deletion if you think that helps more people.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen I'm not sure, if the system is democratic, but please don't let other people (like me) to affect your decisions, you're free to vote down/up or close/reopen, answer or what ever as you wish.

Comment: @Teemu I'm not, and I will. I'm just trying to convince you that you are wrong ;-P

Comment: I'm new to jquery, and I have to disagree that it very clearly told me what was wrong, I had absolutely no clue why CSS wasn't a function. Thanks for helping me, everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a dollar!

```
console.log($("#divID" ).css("display") == "none");
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add $ on line 2 and 3

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){
   console.log($( "#divID" ).css("display") == "none");
   console.log($( "#divID" ).css("display"));
   if($( "#divID" ).css("display") == "none"){
      console.log("showing");
      $("#divID").css("display", "");
   } else {
      console.log("hiding");
      $("#divID").css("display", "none");
   }
   console.log(" ");
});
```